# extract multiple values based on other column

Tags: r, anova

I have this data in r, which I need to make an anova with.

[image]

My problem is, that I only need data out of `Faktor` 0 and 2 but not 1.
I can access one with:

```
FSQ$total_Sum[FSQ$Faktor=="0"]
```

but I don;t know how I can create an anova with only Faktor 0,2.
Here is my current anova code:

```
anova_FSQ_Vor_Nach <- aov(FSQ$Faktor ~FSQ$total_Sum[FSQ$Faktor=="0"])
```

thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may use `subset` for this.

```
# option 1
aov(Faktor ~ total_Sum, data = subset(FSQ, Faktor %in% c(0,2)))

# option 2
with(subset(FSQ, Faktor %in% c(0,2)), aov(Faktor ~ total_Sum))
```

**Output**

```
Call:
   aov(formula = Faktor ~ total_Sum)

Terms:
                total_Sum Residuals
Sum of Squares          0         8
Deg. of Freedom         1         6

Residual standard error: 1.154701
Estimated effects may be unbalanced
```

**Data**

```
FSQ <- data.frame(
  Faktor = rep(c(0,1,2), 4L),
  total_Sum = c(4,23,4,0,0,0,3,3,7,4,0,0)
)
```

Comment: Thank you, it works great. Struggled the whole day with this!

Answer (score 1):

You could create a new dataframe containing only rows where Faktor equals 0 or 2:

```
newFSQ <- FSQ[Faktor == 0 | Faktor == 2,] 

aov(newFSQ$Faktor ~ newFSQ$total_Sum)
```

Comment: Thank you, thought about this as well, but wasn´t sure how to do it, but now I know.

Comment: Tried your answer out, maybe I´m missing a library for it, but needed to access the Faktor via FSQ -> FSQ[FSQ$Faktor == 0 | FSQ$Faktor == 2,]